Job openings data
Where can I get recent (from the past few years) job posting data that is freely available?
It must include these columns:

years of experience required
is temporary/contract?
sector
approximate post date
country

I'm looking for mainly Canada/USA



and optionally:

position filled? when?
sponsorship available? chosen candidate sponsored?
salary

